# Process IDs and fork()

Tags: c, unix, fork

I have an assignment that is asking me to identify the values of the process IDs at lines A, B, C, and D, assuming that the actual pids of the parent and child are 2600 and 2603, respectfully.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
pid_t pid, pid1;
/* fork a child process */
pid = fork();

if (pid < 0) { /* error occurred */
    fprintf(stderr, "Fork Failed");
    return 1;
}
else if(pid == 0){ /* child process */ 
    pid1 = getpid();
    printf("child: pid = %d", pid); /* A */
    printf("child: pid1 = %d", pid1); /* B */
}
else { /* parent process */
    pid1 = getpid();
    printf("parent: pid = %d", pid); /* C */
    printf("parent: pid1 = %d", pid1); /* D */
    wait(NULL);
}
}
```

I've already been given the solutions for the problem, but I'm having trouble understanding the `fork()` function. Why would it return EITHER -1, 0, or some positive number? Why does it not consistently return a certain value? For example, when we assign `pid = fork()`, it can be a value of -1, 0, or some positive number. Even if I know that, I don't know how the values become what they are. I know that, initially, the child process is given a copy of the parent data. Ordinarily, my tactic is to step through the code line-by-line and adjust the variables as they are modified to determine output, but this example seems nondeterministic. I feel like I'm viewing this problem completely wrong, but I don't know how to change my thought process. I've reviewed the documentation for fork() [here](http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/fork/create.html) but it didn't clarify anything for me.

Additionally, why don't we use a get function, i.e. `pid.getID()` in the if/else-if statements? Doesn't this mean that `pid_t` and `int` are equivalent?

A step-by-step explanation of this code would be greatly appreciated.

For reference, the solutions are 0, 2603, 2603, and 2600.

Comment: I think you should read some manual(s). For example: [fork(2) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)

Comment: You're taking a class, didn't they teach you how `fork()` works?

Comment: @MikeCAT He linked to documentation of it in his question. Obviously he isn't able to understand it from them.

Answer (score 3):

`fork()` creates a new process that's an almost exact duplicate of the original process. Both processes continue running, starting from the return of the `fork()` function. In the parent process, `fork()` returns the PID of the child (a positive number), while in the child process `fork()` returns `0` (that's how it knows that it's the child).

If, for some reason, the system wasn't able to create a new process, `fork()` returns `-1` in the parent instead of the child's PID, and `errno` is set to the error code with the reason for the failure.

You could do an equivalent test using `getpid()`, it would just be more work:

```
pid_t parentPID = getpid();
fork();
pid_t myPID = getpid();
if (myPID == parentPID) {
    // this is the parent
} else {
    // this is the child
}
```

Having `fork()` return `0` in the child simplifies it, since you get all the information you need from that one call, instead of having to call `getpid()` twice.

Comment: Are child processes any leaf nodes in the process tree, then?

Comment: Not if they call `fork()` themselves as well.

Comment: All processes except process 0 are child processes.

Comment: It's just like human family trees. Every person is also someone's child, except Adam and Eve.

Comment: So then 'fork()' will return 0 if it does not have its own child, and will return a positive number if it does (assuming an error does not occur)?

Comment: How can a process have children at the moment it's created? They're not tribbles, they're not born pregnant.